# c++ - Call public function with private arguments

Tags: c++, class, function, member

In my class: I want to create a public function which has as argument a private member of the class. And be able to call this function from outside of the class.

Something like that:

```cpp
class MailToTerm
{
    public:
        MailToTerm();
        int getPrivMax(intWithMax priv) {return priv.getMax();} //my public function
        void initPrivMax(intWithMax priv) {return priv.initMax();}
        void getMutexObjPriv(intWithMax priv) {return priv.GetMutexObj();}
        void relMutexObjPriv(intWithMax priv) {return priv.RelMutexObj();}

    private:
        intWithMax cnter_multi_busy ;
        intWithMax cnter_mono_busy ;
        intWithMax cnter_light_busy ;
}

int main(){
    MailToTerm* pt_MailToTerm = new MailToTerm();
    int multi = pt_MailToTerm->getPrivMax(MailToTerm::cnter_multi_busy);
    int mono=   pt_MailToTerm->getPrivMax(MailToTerm::cnter_mono_busy);
}
```

It doesn't work because cnter_multi_busy is seen as "private", so I'm not allowed to access it.
How should I do?

Comment: You shouldn't.  `private` is specifically for stuff you don't want anything but the class screwing around with.  If that's not what you want, it probably shouldn't be private.

Comment: What do you really want to do? A generic accessor for *any* member? The approach you are taking is wrong, `MailToTerm::cnter_multi_busy` used outside of `MailToTerm` is **not** a `intWithMax` but something confusing that I cannot even describe in a simple sentence (`&MailToTerm::cnter_multi_busy` is a pointer to member, but `MailToTerm::cnter_multi_busy` is just a qualified name)

Comment: Don't do it. Examine your design, you shouldn't externalize private members. That's why they're private

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I want a generic function which gives the max of private member passed in parameter (type: intWithMax)

Comment: Edit: I added some examples of others functions I'd like to call, to explain why I want something generic

Comment: Why the `new` and pointers?

Comment: There's nothing right about any of this.  Being told you don't want to do something you obviously want to do can be frustrating...but you should be listening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably make a function that returns what you actually want, such as:

```
class MailToTerm
{
    public:
        MailToTerm();
        int getPrivMaxMulti() { return cnter_multi_busy.getMax(); }
        // repeat for mono. 
    private:
        intWithMax cnter_multi_busy ;
        intWithMax cnter_mono_busy ;
}
```

Alternatively, you could of course make these values public, but that's probably not a great idea.

Another solution is to have an access function for the `cnter_ ...` private members, something like this:

```
class MailToTerm
{
    public:
        MailToTerm();

        int getPrivMax(const intWithMax priv) {return priv.getMax();} //my public function

        const intWithMax getMulti() const { return cnter_multi_busy; }
        // ... as above for mono ... 
    private:
        intWithMax cnter_multi_busy ;
        intWithMax cnter_mono_busy ;
}
```

and then

```
   int multi = pt_MailToTerm->getPrivMax(pt_MailToTerm->getMulti());
```

Comment: Your second suggestion is not too usable. Drop the `getPrivMax` and use `getMulti` or whatever directly. Doing indirection just for the sake of indirection is bad

Comment: Sorry, missed out a const.

Comment: @icepack So would you say that with const, his 2nd suggestion is correct?

Comment: @Gag I'd say call `getMulti` directly. `const` doesn't add much value in this implementation since the data is returned by value any way and the outside user can't change it. Returning by reference, on the other hand, can add some additional value combined with `const`: `const intWithMax& getMulti() const { return cnter_multi_busy; }`. Same goes for the `getPrivMax` arguments - no point making arguments  `const` if passed by value

Answer (score 2):

I like to enumerate options, like this. They can be used in if/else or switch statements easily, and are easy to extend if more options are added later. It also hides the implementation and the private members nicely. Additionaly, the enumerations could be used as indices in an array with the `intWithMax`:s if wanted.

```
class MailToTerm
{
    public:
        enum Options { // or some better name, of course
            CENTER_MULTI_BUSY = 0,
            CENTER_MONO_BUSY
        };
        MailToTerm();
        int getPrivMax(Options o) {
            if (o == CENTER_MULTI_BUSY) return cnter_multi_busy.getMax();
            else if (o == CENTER_MONO_BUSY) return cnter_mono_busy.getMax();
            else // do some error handling
        }

    private:
        intWithMax cnter_multi_busy ;
        intWithMax cnter_mono_busy ;
}

int main() {
    MailToTerm* pt_MailToTerm = new MailToTerm();
    int multi = pt_MailToTerm->getPrivMax(MailToTerm::CENTER_MULTI_BUSY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either make the members public, or make a public wrapper function that calls the original function and passes the private members.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to have a function that does something with a member variable, but want to specify which one in the argument. My solution would be to use an array:

```
class MailToTerm
{
    public:
        enum MemberIndex {
            CNTER_MULTI_BUSY = 0,
            CNTER_MONO_BUSY = 1
        };

        MailToTerm();
        int getPrivMax(MemberIndex index) {return cnter_busy[(int) index].getMax();}

    private:
        intWithMax cnter_busy[2];
};
```

Then call it like this:

```
pt_MailToTerm->getPrivMax(MailToTerm::CNTER_MULTI_BUSY);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MailToTerm
{
    public:
        MailToTerm();
        int getPrivMax() {return cnter_multi_busy.getMax();} //my public function

    private:
        intWithMax cnter_multi_busy ;
        intWithMax cnter_mono_busy ;
}

int main(){
    MailToTerm* pt_MailToTerm = new MailToTerm();
    int multi = pt_MailToTerm->getPrivMax();
}
```

Comment: How does this help to specify which private member the function should use? All you've done is remove the function argument altogether.

Comment: And how would you do it for `pt_MailToTerm->getPrivMax(MailToTerm::cnter_mono_busy);`?

Comment: If he wants to expose his private members, he can write a public getter method for each one.

Comment: Yes I want something generic